# Como realizar uma simples requisição HTTP/GET em Java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-11

Minha dúvida é como realizar uma simples requisição HTTP do tipo GET com **JAVA 11 + Spring**.

Digamos que preciso realizar uma requisição do tipo GET para este end-point([https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/{UserID}](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/%7BUserID%7D)), e a resposta dele irei salvar em um banco de dados. A maneira de salvar no *database* eu sei realizar ela, porém a requisição em si não. Todos os dados que eu tenho utilizado até o momento são *mockados*.

Em **Node.js** é possível realizar uma simples **requisição HTTP** usando o **fetch()**.

**Request:**

```
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json))
```

**Response:**

```
{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "completed": false
}
```

Comment: Amigo de uma olhada em:
J2EE
Eclipse
tomcat > vai precisar de uma IDE que se dê bem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Eai mestre tudo certo?

Tenta utilizar o HttpURLConnection para realizar sua requisição e o GSON para desserializar os objetos JSON

Sobre o HttpURLConnection:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Sobre o GSON:

https://github.com/google/gson

Mais informações:

https://www.paulocollares.com.br/programacao/como-fazer-uma-requisicao-get-de-uma-api-rest-em-java-e-transformar-o-json-em-um-objeto/

Acredito que vá funcionar para o que você precisa:

```
String url = "SEU-ENDPOINT";
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();

conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
    System.out.println("Erro " + conn.getResponseCode() + " ao obter dados da URL " + url);
}

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));

String output = "";
String line;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    output += line;
}

conn.disconnect();

Gson gson = new Gson();
Dados dados = gson.fromJson(new String(output.getBytes()), Dados.class);
```